# How to find the name of the class that defined a method?

Tags: python, types

I'm trying to get the name of the class that defined a method. The method is passed into a function. Within that function, I printed the type of the method, and it shows

```
<class 'method'>
```

but it doesn't tell me what class it belongs to. How can I get the name of the class?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `__func__` attribute of the bound method to see what function it wraps; the string representation of that function should indicate which class (possibly an ancestor, not necessarily the type of the object) defined the function.

```
class A:
    def foo(self):
        pass


class B(A):
    def bar(self):
        pass
```

Then

```
>>> b = B()
>>> type(b.foo)
<class 'method'>
>>> b.foo.__func__
<function A.foo at 0x10f2da0d0>
>>> b.foo.__func__.__qualname__
'A.foo'
```

I don't believe there is any attribute of the function that contains a reference to `A` itself, though you can parse the class name from the qualified function name.

You do, however, know that the class must have come from the MRO of `type(b)`:

```
>>> type(b).mro()
[<class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class 'object'>]
```

so you may be able to take this list and the class name parsed from the qualified name to find the appropriate class:

```
>>> class_list = type(b).mro()
>>> m_class_name = b.foo.__func__.__qualname__.rsplit('.', 1)[0]
>>> [x for x in class_list if x.__name__ == m_class_name][0]
<class '__main__.A'>
```

Comment: You can replace `type(b).mro()` with `b.foo.__self__.__class__.mro()`, so you could write a function that takes a method and returns the defining class by modifying your last snippet a bit. One obvious edge case is that people could redefine classes and given the technique here will be comparing the `__name__` that might fail.

Comment: If all you have is a reference to the bound method, then `m.__self__` is necessary; here, there's little reason to use `b.func.__self__` just to get the same reference that `b` already is. Where possible, I prefer not to access dunder attributes directly; here, `type(x)` is essentially equivalent to `x.__class__`.

Comment: Agreed, I said that because OP mentions in their question: "_The method is passed into a function_"